# A WiFi (countdown) timer for Android?

Tags: android, wifi, timer

I am looking for an Android app that provides an countdown timer after which the WiFi connection is automatically disabled. If WiFi is switched off when starting the app, it should automatically switch on the WiFi connection.

Comment: I don't know any app specifically designed for what you describe, but our Android sister-site has an [automation tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) and my Android website a category for [automation apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation) you could check for help. I could e.g. imagine apps like *Tasker*, *Llama* and *Timeriffic* allowing for a rule like "if WiFi enabled › wait so_long, then disable WiFi" (definitely possible with *Tasker* which I use). This would at least come close to what you're after.